# how to deal with R2 and p-values in Monte Carlo simulations

Tags: regression, p-value, monte-carlo, r-squared

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate R2 and p-values in a Monte Carlo test.

I only had errors in my y variable (`weight` in the example below), so I created random y variables using a normal distribution like below.

```
N=1000
random =  matrix(0,N,length(women$weight)) 
for(i in 1:N) {
  D = women$weight + rnorm(length(women$weight), mean = 0, sd = 1)
  random[i,]=as.matrix(D)
}    
random_trans <- t(as.matrix(random))
```

Then I did a linear regression between my x variables  and my randomly created y variables (like below).

```
M <- matrix(0, ncol(random_trans), ncol = 2)
coef<- as.data.frame(M)
for(i in 1:ncol(random_trans)) {
  randomweight <- random_trans[,i]
  newwomen <- cbind(women, randomweight)
  model <- lm(randomweight ~ height, newwomen)
  M[i,]<- coef(model)
}
colnames(M) <- c("intercept","slope")
colMeans(M)  # slope and intercept
colSds(M)    # errors of slope and intercept
```

In other words, I eventually have results from 1000 linear regressions that give me 1000 slopes and intercepts, and I'm taking the average and standard deviations of those slopes and intercepts for my final slope/intercept and the uncertainties associated with them.

I'm not sure how to deal with R2 and p-value in this case though. It doesn't make sense to calculate R2 and p values like I did with the slopes and intercepts and average them (or does it?). But if I calculate a p-value for the whole 1000 data points then my p value would naturally shoot up since I have so many data points. What would be a good way to calculate R2 and p-value in this case?

Comment: You might consider using the median parameter values, rather than using the means. Ipersonally would use the R-squared (R2) from the final model by calculating "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)"  without using the modeling weights.